# How to access previous activated component from a route resolver triggered by a navigation?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is a container component which has different child routes (`router-outlet`) can navigate within its child component (assume component not change when loading, only change the input param after navigate).

Now I need to access the current child component properties when the router resolving data. But look at the blow 
console.log(), the snapshot component only shows the constructor attributes, instead of the full component properties, methods defined inside of it.

```
@Injectable()
export class ReportResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private router: Router, public route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  resolve() {
    const snapshot = this.route.snapshot;
    console.log(snapshot.component);
  }
}
```

The screenshot is as follow:

[image]

It shows only the component constructor properties, not the whole class properties.

Even I change the injection of `route` as a param of `resolve()`

Answer (score 1):

The component property on ActivatedRouteSnapshot is of below type:-

```
component: Type<any> | string | null;
```

and if you look at the **Type** interface description below:-

(https://angular.io/api/core/Type#description),

it will represent the constructor function. I believe that's why it shows constructor instead of class properties.

Comment: I changed to access the component in a guard then. Thanks